# Unobtrusive ajax - View being fully replaced by partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have searched multiple examples and have tried several things to get this to work properly. Currently I am trying to get a div to be replaced by using an Ajax.HtmlLink pointing to a PartialViewResult method.

### I have tried

- Checking network and javascript consoles to make sure my .js are all being loaded
- Unbundling the stock jqueryval bundle and including the scripts manually
- Double checked I didn't have another DOM element with the same update target Id
- Checked my ajaxoptions to ensure everything was correct

I know unobtrusive is working because my Email duplicate remote validation check is working.

I will now show some screen shots of my debugging process
[image]
[image]

### Here is what the page looks like prior to ajax load

My goal is to replace the container on the right that is currently holding email, name, and zipcode values

[image]

### Here is the result##

[image]

### This is what my view code looks like

```
<div class="container">
<br />
<br />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="sidebar-account">
            <div class="row ">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">My Account</div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <ul class="nav">
                                <li>
                                    <a class="active" href="account_dashboard.html">Me</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    @Ajax.ActionLink("Alerts", "ManageAlerts", null, new AjaxOptions
                               {
                                   HttpMethod = "GET",
                                   UpdateTargetId = "ajax-update",
                                   InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                                   OnBegin = "ajaxBegin",
                                   OnFailure = "ajaxFail",
                                   OnComplete = "ajaxComplete",
                                   OnSuccess = "ajaxSuccess"
                               }, new { @class = "active" })
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a class="active" href="account_account.html">Linked Accounts</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a class="active" href="account_ads.html">Manage ads</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a class="active" href="account_ad_create.html">Create new ad</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row hidden-xs">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="well">
                        <div class="row ">
                            <div class="col-lg-3">
                                <img src="css/images/icons/Crest.png" width="45" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-9">

                                <h4 style="margin-top: 0">Increase visibility</h4>
                                <p>Don't forget to 'bump' your listing to gain more visibility</p>

                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <div id="ajax-update">
            @Html.Partial("_ManageUserAccount", Model)
        </div>

    </div>
    <br />

</div>
```

### Partial View Code##

```
<div id="fadein-div">
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">@Model.Username : Alerts</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <br />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <p><span style="font-weight:bold">Change your alerts!</span></p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <br />

        @using (Html.BeginForm("ManageAlerts", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-vertical", role = "form" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <fieldset>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 ">

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-2">
                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(P => P.EmailAlertsOn) @Html.LabelFor(P => P.EmailAlertsOn)
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <div id="control-div">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <h3>Email alert options</h3>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(P => P.EmailOnNewMessageOn) @Html.LabelFor(P => P.EmailOnNewMessageOn)
                                </div>
                                <div class="text-danger">
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(P => P.EmailOnNewMessageOn)
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(P => P.EmailOnReplyOn) @Html.LabelFor(P => P.EmailOnReplyOn)
                                </div>
                                <div class="text-danger">
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(P => P.EmailOnReplyOn)
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(P => P.EmailOnAccountUpdateOn) @Html.LabelFor(P => P.EmailOnAccountUpdateOn)
                                </div>
                                <div class="text-danger">
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(P => P.EmailOnAccountUpdateOn)
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>


                        <br />
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save details</button> &nbsp;&nbsp;


                    </div>




                </div>
            </fieldset>
        }


    </div>
</div>
```

### And finally, controller code##

```
 [HttpGet]
    public PartialViewResult ManageAlerts()
    {
        var user = UserManager.FindById(Guid.Parse(User.Identity.GetUserId()));
        Models.Account.ManageAlertsViewModel vm = new ManageAlertsViewModel();
        vm.Username = user.UserName;
        vm.EmailAlertsOn = user.EmailAlertsOn;
        vm.EmailOnAccountUpdateOn = user.EmailOnAccountUpdateOn;
        vm.EmailOnNewMessageOn = user.EmailOnNewMessageOn;
        vm.EmailOnReplyOn = user.EmailOnReplyOn;

        return PartialView("_ManageAlerts", vm);
    }  


<!-- js library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Themes/Authenticity%20Forms/Authenty/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Themes/Authenticity%20Forms/Authenty/js/jquery.icheck.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Themes/Authenticity%20Forms/Authenty/js/waypoints.min.js"></script>

<!-- authenty js -->
<script src="~/Themes/Authenticity%20Forms/Authenty/js/authenty.js"></script>

<!-- preview scripts -->
<script src="~/Themes/Authenticity%20Forms/Authenty/js/preview/jquery.malihu.PageScroll2id.js"></script>
<script src="~/Themes/Authenticity%20Forms/Authenty/js/preview/jquery.address-1.6.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Themes/Authenticity%20Forms/Authenty/js/preview/scrollTo.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Themes/Authenticity%20Forms/Authenty/js/preview/init.js"></script>



@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

Comment: You need `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js`

Comment: so `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` is not the same thing?

Comment: No. The first is for ajax methods, the second for client side validation.

Comment: Ah okay. I could've sworn all required .js files were included in the mvc 5 template. I have to download this and try it out. Will report back.